# Transcription of two different factors from the same transcription factor - seeking a relation between concentrations

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, transcription-factor

Let's assume that:

Factor $X$ enters nucleus and results in the transcription of two different factors, $A$, and  $B$.

$X$ $\to$ $A$

$X$ $\to$ $B$

Can it be expressed as

$[A]=\alpha [X]$ or  $[A]=\frac{\theta (\alpha [X])^n}{1+(\alpha [X])^n}$ and

$[B]=\beta [X]$ or  $[B]=\frac{\theta (\beta [X])^n}{1+(\beta [X])^n}$

where $\theta$ is the Hill coefficient, such that concentrations of A and B have a relation between?

Note: I don't have an education on molecular biology, or biology - terminology might be wrong.

Comment: This question definitely needs more details and clarity, especially regarding the Hill coefficient, what $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $n$ are, and what specifically your question is. However, from what I do understand, from a biological perspective the answer is "not necessarily". It is entirely possible that one or both of the factors $A$ or $B$ has an inhibitory effect on the activity of $X$, causing it to be produced more slowly (and eventually turned off) as its concentration increases. This is actually a very common occurrence, and doesn't seem to be accounted for in your equations.

Comment: @MattDMo thank you for writing a comment, X, A and B are known factors, X is the nucleus triggering factor of a long molecular cascade. A and B effects the upper factors on the cascade and after $\delta t$ they effect X too but I am focused on the immediate time step between X and transcripted factors. $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $n$ are hypothetical. I hope it clarified things a bit.